# How do breadth and width differ in this sentence?

Tags: difference, nouns

> The sun was just above the western sky-line, and the evening was a particularly bright and clear one, so that the whole extent of the plateau was visible beneath me. — *It was, as seen from this height, of an oval contour, with a **breadth** of about thirty miles and a **width** of twenty.* — Its general shape was that of a shallow funnel, all the sides sloping down to a considerable lake in the center.

---

Source:
[The Lost World](https://books.google.hu/books?id=Ti6cCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT131&lpg=PT131&dq=%22it%20was%20as%20seen%20from%20this%20height%22&source=bl&ots=hracKm0YPQ&sig=_adTMsuifV4FyuuKZdfDtLSvoV0&hl=hu&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9paudmMLJAhUJnXIKHTYBBFoQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22it%20was%20as%20seen%20from%20this%20height%22&f=false)

Comment: Not very well. This is a bad phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Width** is typically understood to refer to a line that is parallel to the line that connects the shoulders of the onlooker (i.e. left-right).

When we say a **breadth of country** we are conceiving of an expanse which is not oriented in a particular way relative to an onlooker.

https://books.google.com/books?id=2Ck-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1416&dq=%22breadth+of+country%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqwfvLocLJAhXG2SYKHanGCIEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22breadth%20of%20country%22&f=false

So, given the fact that we have a width, by process of elimination, I would say that **breadth** here  must refer to how far the country extends perpendicular to left-right.

But I would not wager much money on that opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Either **breadth** or **width** can refer to how wide something is i.e. side-to-side

> John held his arms apart showing the width of the tree trunk

The other word (**width** / **breadth**) would refer to the other (second) dimension. In the example given, **depth** would be the third dimension describing how far down the valley goes.

In the example:

> Travel the **length** and **breadth** of the country.

**Length** refers to north/south (head-to-toe), and **breadth** refers to east/west (side-to-side).